# Why log4j2 syslog send 2 messages in one packet

Tags: java, log4j2

We have application when we logging some messages into syslog. Sometimes when we have huge traffic (2 log in same time) syslog log 2 messages in same packet:

this is message from tcpdump:

```
413 62.346560   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   Syslog  698 LOCAL3.INFO: 1 2015-12-21T17:49:14.239+01:00 myserver.i.cz zip:/TestServertmp/_WL_user/my-app/zh0o33/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/log4j2.xml - - - MyService|SD|21.12.2015 17:49:14.239|21.12.2015 13:22:16|8e8c46f5-5112-4fe2-ae27-4d9a1bc6f601|46cf84c9-0135-4e71-9a96-89f3fd6b562c\n<158>1 2015-12-21T17:49:14.239+01:00 myserver.i.cz zip:/TestServertmp/_WL_user/my-app/zh0o33/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/log4j2.xml - - - MyService|SD|21.12.2015 17:49:14.239|21.02.2014 07:56:07|074006c1-8105-4b21-8e2c-cca30cea98b4|36eea480-cc23-4f46-ace1-12839c97f7e6\n
```

as you can see `<158>` means start another log message (priority) which means local3.info but syslog send it in one package. Why ? This happens just 1-2 times per hours. I am using upd  which means I already had immediatelyFlush to true

**UPDATE:**

Can someone explain me why log4j2 use readLock instead of writeLock when appending data in abstractOutputStream ?

```
private final ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private final Lock readLock = rwLock.readLock();


@Override
public void append(final LogEvent event) {
    readLock.lock();
    try {
        final byte[] bytes = getLayout().toByteArray(event);
        if (bytes.length > 0) {
            manager.write(bytes);
            if (this.immediateFlush || event.isEndOfBatch()) {
                manager.flush();
            }
        }
    } catch (final AppenderLoggingException ex) {
        error("Unable to write to stream " + manager.getName() + " for appender " + getName());
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        readLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: The readLock is probably meant to ensure that reading getLayout and manager is atomic. manager.write handles its own synchronization.

Comment: yea but code could do 2 times write and just once flush what as wrong. Anyways it is fixed in version 2.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was bug which should be fixed in newest version: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1230